# Create Python string placeholder (%s) n times

Tags: string, list, python-2.7, tuples, placeholder

I am looking to automatically generate the following string in Python 2.7 using a loop based on the number of columns in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname) VALUES (534737, 100.115)
```

This assumes that the DataFrame has 2 columns.

Here is what I have:

```
# Generate test numbers for table:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=['firstname','lastname'])

# Create list of tuples from numbers in each row of DataFrame:
list_of_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

Now, I create the string:
Manually - this works:

```
add_SQL = INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname) VALUES %s" % (list_of_tuples[4])
```

In this example, I only used 2 column names - `'firstname'` and `'lastname'`. But I must do this with a loop since I have 156 column names - I cannot do this manually.

What I need:

1. I need to automatically generate the placeholder `%s` the same
   number of times as the number of columns in the Pandas DataFrame.
   Here, the DataFrame has 2 columns so I need an automatic way to
   generate `%s` twice.
2. Then I need to create a tuple with 2 entries,
   without the `''`.

My attempt:

```
sss = ['%s' for x in range(0,len(list(df)))]
add_SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (" + sss + ") VALUES %s" % (len(df), list_of_tuples[4])
```

But this is not working.

Is there a way for me to generate this string automatically?

Comment: I'm not really clear on how your attempt is supposed to match what you have above: above, you have `(firstname, lastname)`, but in your attempt, it looks like you just want `(%s, %s)`, though you're using `len(df)` which is just going to give you a number... do you want column names, or do you want literal `%s`?

Comment: But in any event, if you just want `%s` placeholders, we can build that string first: `placeholder = ",".join(["%s"]*len(df))`, and then `add_SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (placeholder, placeholder)`. If you actually want column names and values, make two initial strings: `column_names = ",".join(columns)` and `values = ",".join(values)` and use them instead of placeholder appropriately, where `columns` and `values` are lists you have lying around (`values = list_of_tuples[i]`, for example).

Comment: With parts of your solution, I posted a reply below as the "answer", but there is still a question since I can't seem to get your exact layout in one line. See the post ("Answer") below and let me know what you think in the comments below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with - it is based on dwanderson's approach in the 2nd comment of the original post (question):

```
table_name = name_a #name of table

# Loop through all columns of dataframe and generate one string per column:
cols_n = df.columns.tolist()
placeholder = ",".join(["%s"]*df.shape[1]) #df.shape[1] gives # of columns
column_names = ",".join(cols_n)
insrt = "INSERT INTO %s " % table_name
for qrt in range(0,df.shape[0]):
   add_SQL_a_1 = insrt + "(" + column_names + ") VALUES (" + placeholder + ")" #part 1/2
   add_SQL_a_2 = add_SQL_a_1 % list_of_tuples[qrt] #part 2/2
```

This way, the final string is in part 2/2.

For some reason, it would not let me do this all in one line and I can't figure out why.

Comment: dwanderson, any thoughts as to why the string could not be assembled in one line?